# Generate UUID for Postgres JSON document

Tags: json, postgresql, uuid

I'm inserting into a Postgres table with a JSON document and I want to generate a unique ID for the document. I can do that on my own, of course, but I was wondering if there was a way to have PG do it.

```
INSERT INTO test3 (data) VALUES ('{"key": "value", "unique": ????}')
```

The docs seem to indicate that JSON records fit into various SQL data types, but I don't see how that actually works.

Comment: The SQL you have there doesn't make any sense; as far as Postgres is concerned, the entire JSON document is one value, so you would specify it all as a string, like `... VALUES( '{"key": "value"}' )`, not as separate keys "floating" in the SQL.

Comment: [uuid_generate_v4()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html#idm46428633635312)

Comment: @IMSoP, that's a good point. I should've put the braces in there. Fixed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure how I'd pass uuid_generate_v4() as a value in a JSON string.

Comment: Do you really need it inside the JSON? Normally you'd put a UUID in the table's primary key. Just because you can use JSON inside the database doesn't mean you should should have a bunch of single column tables.

Comment: @muistooshort Normally, yes, but I'm converting an application from a pure document store to pg, so my table is literally a one column JSON field. I certainly could factor out the more "rectangular" elements, but it would require more fiddling to make this transparent to the final application (which is the goal since I may need to switch between DBMSes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just concatenating? Assuming your column is of type json/jsonb, something like the following should work:

```
INSERT INTO test3 (data) VALUES (('{"key": "value", "unique": "' || uuid_generate_v4() || '"}')::jsonb)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to generate a UUID and store it at the same time as a value within a JSON data field, here is something some may find to be a little more sane:

```
WITH
    -- Create a temporary view named "new_entry" containing your data
    new_entry
        -- This is how you name the view's columns
        ("key", "unique")
    AS (
        VALUES
            -- This is the actual row returned by the view
            (
                'value',
                uuid_generate_v4()
            )
    )
INSERT INTO
    test3(
        data
    )
    SELECT
        -- Convert row to JSON. Column name = key, column value = value.
        ROW_TO_JSON(new_entry.*)
    FROM
        new_entry
```

First, we're creating a temporary view named `new_entry`, which containing all of the data want to store in a `JSON` data field.

Second, we're grabbing that entry and passing it to the `ROW_TO_JSON` function which converts it to a valid JSON data type. Once converted, it's then inserting the row into the `test3` table.

My reasoning for the "sanity" is that more than likely, your `JSON` object will end up containing more than just two key/value pairs... Rather, you'll end up with a hand full of keys and values, in which it'll be up to you to ensure you don't miss any quotes and escape user input appropriately. Why glue all of this together manually when you can have Postgres do it for you (with the help of `ROW_TO_JSON()`) while at the same time, making it easier to read and debug?